# Stylesheet not loading on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a problem with Bootstrap not loading responsive stylesheet. It loads fine on desktop browser and it responds on screen size when it is re-sized on desktop but not on Mobile browsers.

The url is `http://176.9.5.243/~marin/ranktracker/index.html`

How can I re-size on mobile browsers?

Comment: You should load your `reset` stylesheet first, then your web fonts, then your library stylesheets and *then* your own stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser have own pre-defined stylesheet. Try this CSS reset:

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/meyer-reset/